# nginx ingress redirect a path and strict-validate-path-type: "Prefix"

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I want to mitigate [CVE-2022-4886 vulnerability](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/10570), so I have this config in configMap of nginx-ingress:

```
strict-validate-path-type: "Prefix"
```

and also I have this rewrite inside kind:ingress:

```
set $version v1;
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$version $1 last;
```

Is it possible that the strict-validate-path-type: "Prefix" cause the rewrite to not work?
How can I fix it and also mitigate the vulnerbility?